# How to get a count of data for every date in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get data to populate a multi-line graph. The table jobs has the columns id, created_at, and partner_id. I would like to display the sum of jobs for each partner_id each day. My current query has 2 problems. 1) It is missing a lot of jobs. 2) It only contains an entry for a given day if there was a row on that day. My current query is where start is an integer denoting how many days back we are looking for data:

```
SELECT d.date, count(j.id), j.partner_id FROM (
  select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AS date 
  FROM generate_series(0, #{start}, 1) 
  AS offs
) d 
JOIN (
  SELECT jobs.id, jobs.created_at, jobs.partner_id FROM jobs
  WHERE jobs.created_at > now() - INTERVAL '#{start} days'
) j
ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', j.created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
GROUP BY d.date, j.partner_id
ORDER BY j.partner_id, d.date;
```

This returns records like the following:

```
[{"date"=>"2019-06-21", "count"=>3, "partner_id"=>"099"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-22", "count"=>1, "partner_id"=>"099"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-21", "count"=>3, "partner_id"=>"075"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-23", "count"=>1, "partner_id"=>"099"}]
```

what I want is something like this:

```
[{"date"=>"2019-06-21", "count"=>3, "partner_id"=>"099"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-22", "count"=>1, "partner_id"=>"099"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-21", "count"=>3, "partner_id"=>"075"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-22", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>"075"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-23", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>"075"},
{"date"=>"2019-06-23", "count"=>1, "partner_id"=>"099"}]
```

So that for every day in the query I have an entry for every partner even if that count is 0. How can I adjust the query to populate data even when the count is 0?

Comment: You need `OUTER JOIN`. In your case - `LEFT`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Why? Do we need dates outside the range?

Comment: I have tried all the mentioned joins so far and the data is still not being pulled correctly. It is missing, not only counts where it is 0, but also not pulling counts where I can confirm there should be data.

Comment: @PM77-1 sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`.  You also don't need so many subqueries and there is no need to translate to a date to a string and then back to a date:

```
SELECT d.date, count(j.id), j.partner_id
FROM (SELECT to_char(dte, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date , dte
      FROM generate_series(current_date - {start} * interval '1 day', current_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
     ) d LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON DATE_TRUNC('day', j.created_at) = d.dte
GROUP BY d.date, j.partner_id
ORDER BY j.partner_id, d.date;
```

Comment: The output I got from this is: [{"date"=>"2019-09-04", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-05", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-06", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-07", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-08", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-09", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-10", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil},
   {"date"=>"2019-09-11", "count"=>0, "partner_id"=>nil}]